# scala upgrade to Java 8

Tags: java, scala, lift

I get errors similar to following when I upgrade to Java 8.

> [error] error while loading CharSequence, class file
>   '/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.101-3.b13.el6_8.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/CharSequence.class)' is broken [error] (bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 10) [error] error
>   while loading AnnotatedElement, class file
>   '/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.101-3.b13.el6_8.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.class)'
>   is broken

Answers tell me to upgrade to scala 2.10.3+ but I use the following plugins. my build.sbt is as follows:

```
name := "test"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion:= "2.9.1"

seq(webSettings: _*)

scanDirectories in Compile := Nil

port in container.Configuration := 8080

checksums in update := Nil
```

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Sonatype's Maven repository" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/scala-tools/",
  "Java.net Maven2 Repository" at "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
)

`libraryDependencies ++= {`
 `val liftVersion = "2.4-M4" // Put the current/latest lift`
 `Seq("net.liftweb" %% "lift-webkit" % liftVersion % "compile-default",`
 `"net.liftweb" %% "lift-mapper" % liftVersion % "compile->default",`
  `"net.liftweb" %% "lift-wizard" % liftVersion % "compile->default",`
   `"net.liftweb" %% "lift-textile" % liftVersion % "compile->default",`
   `"net.databinder" %% "dispatch-core"  % "0.8.8",`
    `"net.databinder" %% "dispatch-oauth" % "0.8.8",`
    `"net.databinder" %% "dispatch-nio" % "0.8.8"`
    `)`
`}`

`// when using the sbt web app plugin 0.2.4+, use "container" instead of "jetty"for the context`
`// Customize any further dependencies as desired`
`libraryDependencies ++= Seq(`
 `"org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-server" % "8.0.4.v20111024" % "container", // For Jetty 8`
`"org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "8.0.4.v20111024" % "container",`
`"org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-jsp-2.1" % "7.5.4.v20111024" % "container",`
`"org.mortbay.jetty" % "jsp-2.1-glassfish" % "9.1.1.B60.25.p2" % "container",`
`"javax.servlet" % "servlet-api" % "2.5" % "provided->default",`
`"com.mongodb.casbah" %% "casbah" % "2.1.5-1" % "compile->default",`
`"net.liftweb" %% "lift-mongodb-record" % "2.4-M5" % "compile->default",`
`"net.liftweb" %% "lift-widgets" % "2.4-M5" % "compile->default",`
 `"org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "0.3.1" % "compile->default",`
 `"net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "XXX",`
 `"org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.1.2",`
 `"ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.2" % "compile->default",`
 `"org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.1" % "compile->default",`
`"commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.3" % "compile->default"`
`)`

for example

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/liftweb/lift-textile

is not available for 2.10.

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/mongodb/casbah/

is not available for 2.10 etc.

So am I stuck with Java 7 or is there a way out to upgrade to Java 8?

Comment: Try using new java package. It might have been incomplete

Comment: How do I figure out that the Java package is incomplete? All other java applications seem to work ok for me.                                                                   # java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_101"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
[root@mtznjv2nslt01 ~]# alternatives --config java

Comment: Its a guess... I've been through similar issue....

Comment: I see the same issue even after upgrading the latest one available through yum.                                                                                        
# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_161"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b14, mixed mode)

Comment: I don't have idea regarding openJDK.....I'm using oracleJDK....you might try using oracle JDK but not sure it'll help